# MySQL, Short WHERE query

Tags: mysql

Here is my example query.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '1' OR `id` = '8' OR `id` = '12'
```

Is there a quicker way for WHERE part?

Comment: certainly, `IN` is quicker to write. But there is no performance difference. This is micro-benchmarking. SQL engines are smart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the IN clause:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE `id` IN ('1', '8','12')
```

Since the query optimizer will convert this query into an execution plan which will be very similar to the sequence of ORs it won't really make a performance difference.  It's about aesthetics and/or less typing :)

Comment: Which one is better? Using IN or \`id\` = '1' OR \`id\` = '8' OR \`id\` = '12'

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it runs faster, but it may read more cleanly:

```
SELECT * ... WHERE ID in ('1', '8', '12' )
```

Comment: Internally it will be converted to a bunch of ORs when it goes to run the query.

Comment: For readability, I would use the IN clause for sure.  And as Quassnoi and Mark point out, the performance will be the same.  I was not sure with mysql if there would be a difference although I was pretty sure it would be the same.  I work on a different SQL engine in which case I do know they are equivalent.  I would imagine they are optimized identically in most/all SQL engines, but one never knows for sure.

Answer (score 1):

To check for multiple potential values in a where clause for the same field, you need to use `IN`.

In your example, you would use:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `id` IN (1, 8, 12)
```

This feature is also useful for using subqueries, such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `id` IN (
    SELECT `id`
    FROM `table2`
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the second example.